# VBA (excel 2010) if error (like #N/A) then move to next row

Tags: vba, excel

Experts!

I am trying to automate a manual process and am running into (I'm sure) an easy fix. There are about 8 columns that may contain the results of an index/match formula that I need to copy into column B. For example, Column 'A' is an IP address, and column 'B' needs to have a value from one of the columns "C" through "K". The logic needs to first look in 'K' then move descending towards 'C', checking if the value is first an error (like #N/A or 0). If no error exists then copy that value into a summary sheet. I think my real obstacle is that I cannot get the logic right to check for an error. It either does nothing (which I suspect I am just exiting the loop) or it just copies everything regardless. Assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
Sub MakeSummary()
    Dim oRng1 As Range, oRng2 As Range
    Dim oWS1 As Worksheet, oWS2 As Worksheet, i As Long

    ' Initial cell to check
    Set oWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Set oRng1 = oWS1.Range("A1")

    ' Initial cell to store
    Set oWS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set oRng2 = oWS2.Range("A1")

    ' Clear original data on Summary
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng2.Offset(i, 0))
        oRng2.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    ' Look for IPs on "Master", then put in to "Summary"
    ' If value in cell is #N/A or 0, then skip to next cell

    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng1)
                If oRng1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(oRng1.Formula) Then
                Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(0, 1)
                Else
                oRng2.Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 1).Value ' IPs
                oRng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 2).Value ' 1st Match
                oRng2.Offset(0, 2).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, 3).Value ' 2nd Match
                Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to store

        Set oRng1 = oRng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check

    Loop


    ' Clean up
    Set oRng1 = Nothing
    Set oWS1 = Nothing
    Set oRng2 = Nothing
    Set oWS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError` to check the formula result to see if it is an error.  In which case your code would look like this (edited to make use of the `IsError()` function mentioned in the comments

```
    Sub MakeSummary2()


    Dim oRng1 As Range
    Dim oRng2 As Range
    Dim oWS1 As Worksheet
    Dim oWS2 As Worksheet
    Dim X As Integer

    ' Initial cell to check
    Set oWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
    Set oRng1 = oWS1.Range("A2")

    ' Initial cell to store
    Set oWS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set oRng2 = oWS2.Range("A2")


    ' Clear original data on Summary

    oWS2.Cells.Clear

    ' Look for IPs on "Master", then put in to "Summary"
    ' If value in cell is #N/A or 0, then skip to next cell

    Do Until IsEmpty(oRng1)
        If IsError(oRng1.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
            For X = 10 To 2 Step -1
                If Not IsError(oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value) Then
                    If oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value <> "" Or oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value <> 0 Then
                        oRng2.Value = oRng1.Value
                        oRng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value
                        Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1, 0)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next X
            If X = 1 And oRng2.Value = "" Then
                oRng2.Value = oRng1.Value
                oRng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No Data"
                Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Else
            oRng2.Value = oRng1.Value
            oRng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value
            Set oRng2 = oRng2.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
        Set oRng1 = oRng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop
End Sub
```

This will place the value of "No Data" in column B in the event that all of the data in columns C:K are either errors, empty, or 0's

Comment: Note: a similar function `IsError` is available in VBA, no need to prefix it with `Application.WorksheetFunction.`

Comment: Hmmm.. still is copying the errors. Is that because the values are actually formulas and not just "N/A"?

Comment: @MikeS - can you  provide a sample of the data?

Comment: of course... try this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2M8DnCQpk3URk92T2NlaDNlVkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, either a value from the lookup or #N/A and sometimes 0 for some reason

Comment: I've updated my answer with code that works on the sample data you gave me regardless of if there is anything in the columns or not

Comment: Works great!! One question, What does X = 10 to 2 Step -1 do?

Comment: Also, how would I Iterate through multiple columns? Is that the X = 10 to 2 Step -1 statement?

Comment: @MikeS - In this case, yes.  the line of code `X = 10 to 2 Step -1` counts down from 10 to 2 by subtracting 1 each time.  using the value of `X` in the line of code `oRng1.Offset(0, X).Value` references the cell offset.  In this case when **X = 10** the column referenced is **K** and as **X** counts down we are moving backwards through the columns

X = 10 = K, X = 9 = J, X = 8 = I,...., X = 2 = C